# Brownian motion reflected at a trailing barrier

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X_t$ be a Brownian motion with positive drift starting at 0. The process with reflection at fixed barrier $b<0$ (sometimes called a "regulated Brownian motion") is:

\begin{equation}
\label{fixed-barrier}
Y_t = X_t + \max\left\{ 0, \,\, \max_{0 \le n \le t}(b - X_n)\right\}.     
\end{equation}

Consider instead $Z_t$ constructed by starting at $Z_0=X_0$ and then reflecting $X_t$ at a "trailing barrier" which starts at the same $b <0$ as above, but then increases whenever $Z_t$ attains a new maximum :

\begin{equation}
\label{trailing-barrier}
Z_t = X_t + \max\left\{ 0, \,\,\max_{0 \le n\ \le t}\left(\max_{0 \le i \le n}(b+\,Z_i - X_n)\right)\right\}.
\end{equation}

I want to find the transition density (or say something else useful) for this $Z_t$: a Brownian motion reflected at a trailing barrier, where the barrier is a fixed distance below the running maximum of the reflected process.

Here’s a simulation of $X_t$ (red) and $Z_t$ (blue) with $b=-0.6$. We can see that the reflecting barrier (dashed blue line) often stays fixed for extended periods; it moves only at times when $Z_t$ reaches a new maximum.

[Drifting Brownian motion reflected at trailing barrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLPGg.jpg)

The brown stepped line in the version below shows the amount added to $X_t$ to construct $Z_t$.

[Amount added to construct Z_t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGzkb.jpg)

Reference:
Here is the solution for the fixed barrier version https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:CSEM.0000049491.13935.af

Comment: Any article references on studying this particular process $Z_{t}$ or something close to it? The reflected Brownian motion is at least defined directly, whereas $Z_{t}$ is defined recursively which makes it more tricky, so it will be interesting any articles that study a similarly recursive object.

Comment: As in that article, a main goal is defining the corresponding pde problem.  Do you think you can write this as ,say, some stochastic control problem?

Comment: I have not found any references on $Z_t$ (but I am not a specialist in this area). The exponentiated version of the process arose in an application, i.e. starting from 1 with the reflecting barrier at $0 < e^b < 1$ times the running maximum.